# order by primary key

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, primary-key

I'm trying to do a comparison between the data of a table of a SQLServer database before and after some action.
I'm saving the first data in a file (actually I'm saving the MD5 of the data, but not relevant), so I can compare the new data with it after the action.
The first problem is that the data returned by the query is not always in the same order.

So to solve this problem I thought about using the ORDER BY clause to order the data.
Here comes the second problem. I'm executing a query defined by the user, so the query, and the table may be different.

So here is the question: How can I ORDER BY the PRIMARY_KEY (one or multiple) without previous knowledge of what table will be used??

Any other solution will be also welcomed,

Thanks for your time and effort,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql and query the meta tables to discover what the primary key is

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND table_name = 'Person'
```

With dynamic sql you construct your sql statement like a string and hand it over to sp_executeSQL

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to do a comparison between the data of a table of a
>   SQLServer database before and after some action.

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Do you really need to order by the primary key? If not you can do

```
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

that will order by column 1, 2 and 3 regardless the name of the column. 
That would work on the PK if you have your Primary key on the first column of the table

Comment: thanks, but I try to do the most flexible solution for different versions, and yes I do need to order by primary key, for your solution I'll need to previously know the number of columns in the table.

Thanks anyway... ;)